# NGINX authentication with role based access

Tags: nginx, rbac

So first of all, I'm very new to NGINX, Docker etc..

But here is my scenario:

I've created a 2 docker images which display a simple website, website1 and website2.
Both of them are created in a dockerfile, using the nginx image.

I put them in 2 seperate containers.

By visiting localhost:8080 I got website1.
By visiting localhost:8081 I got website2.

Then I wanted just 1 entrypoint (localhost) and by using a /, going to my websites.

So I created a new container, called reverseproxy.
I used default.conf of NGINX to proxy pass to my containers.
I did the following:
in default.conf, I have 3 locations. localhost (which shows the default NGINX page)
localhost/website1, which proxy passes this to my website1
localhost/webiste2, which proxy passes this to my website2
I put all of this is a docker-compose.yaml file and it runs just fine.

Then for website1, I wanted basic authentication. With using apache-utils and adding basic authentication to my /webiste1 and /website2 end points, it works great.

But now I want to restrict access to my endpoints (website 1 and website 2) based on specific roles.

So when I visit website1, enter credentials using basic_auth, I want to be able to check whether this user has the role of user for example.
And when visiting /website2, I want to be able to login, but then restrict access because this user may not access this website, only with the "admin" role for example.

I've been stuck on this for a few days now...

Anyone have any idea?

Just some extra information: I don't want to use Kubernetes. I know this has RBAC (Role based Access Control) but I'd like to keep it more simple.

Thanks for your input in advance :)

Completely stuck..

Answer (score 0):

You can use and leverage the **OAuth-proxy** : https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy

Here is the demo on Github if you are looking for same : https://github.com/deskoh/nginx-oauth2-proxy-demo

You can also use the **ngx_openresty**